# My app doesn't open file when I double click it and the app is not running yet

Tags: macos, cocoa

My app can open the type of file it is supposed to work with when I double click the file, AND the app is already running. However, when the app is not running yet and i double click a file, the app starts, but it does not open the file. Why could that be?

The app delegate implements the methods: 

`-(void) application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames {
    for (NSString *name in filenames) {
        NSLog(@"Openning files");
        [self.topController addFileAtPath:name];
    }
}
-(BOOL) application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename {
    NSLog(@"Openning file_");
    [self.topController addFileAtPath:filename];
    return YES;
}`

Answer (score 1):

For those who might fall into the same trap:

Turns out, the methods above get called earlier than the "-applicationDidFinishLaunching:", in which I was doing all my app initialisation. I ended up creating an "alive" flag (to show if my app has been inited yet), and put all my initialization logic in a separate method. Then, in my "...finishedLaunching", "openFiles" and "openFile" i check whether that flag is on or off, and call the application initialization method accordingly:

`@implementation DTVAppDelegate
BOOL alive = NO;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if (!alive) {
        [self startApp];
    }
}
- (void) startApp {
    // init logic
    alive = YES;
}
-(void) application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames {
    if (!alive) {
        [self startApp];
    }
    for (NSString *name in filenames) {
        NSLog(@"Openning files");
        [self.topController addFileAtPath:name];
    }
}`

Comment: You can avoid this hack, if you do the app initialization not in applicationDidFinishLaunching: but in the earlier called applicationWillFinishLaunching: